# Show that $f$ is a constant function.

Tags: functions, proof-verification

**Problem**

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function such that for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and for all $t\geqslant 0$, $$f(x)=f(e^tx)$$Show that $f$ is a constant function.

**My proof**

Take $t=1$. Then for any fixed $r \in \mathbb{R}$, it's clear that $$f(r)=f \left(\frac{r}{e}\right)=f \left(\frac{r}{e^{2}}\right)=f \left(\frac{r}{e^{3}}\right)=\cdots=f \left(\frac{r}{e^{n}}\right).$$Take the limits of both sides as $n \to \infty$. Notice that $\dfrac{r}{e^n} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$. By the continuity of $f(x)$, we have $$f(r)=\lim_{n \to \infty}f(r)=\lim_{n \to \infty}f \left(\frac{r}{e^{n}}\right)=f\left(\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{r}{e^{n}}\right)=f(0).$$This shows that $f(x) \equiv f(0)$.

*Please Correct me if I'm wrong.*

Comment: Looks good to me. The most important part is to use continuity of $f$ in the step $$\lim_{n \to +\infty} f(r/e^n) = f\left(\lim_{n\to +\infty} r/e^n\right) = f(0),$$and you paid attention to that.

Comment: The t=1 part is unclear. From then on you use negative powers of e.

Comment: @FranciscoJoséLetterio Sir, please notice the premise. Since $f(x)=f(e^tx)$ holds for any $t \geq 0$, then it necessarily holds for $t=1$, because of $1 \geq 0$. Maybe you needn't take $t=1$, and you may let $t$ be $t$ itself, but thus there exists a diificulty in subsequent process, Since $t$ may equal $0$, you will get nothing when you take the limits.

Comment: From your proof you can see that only continuity at $x=0$ is necessary to conclude that equation that $f$ is constant. Now you can try dropping continuity altogether. In that case, you can prove that $f$ is constant for $x>0$, and also constant (perhaps different constant) for $x<0$. This means that if instead of continuity, they give you only $f(0)=f(1)=f(-1)$, then it again follows that $f$ is constant.

Comment: @elmer Yes,you're right. We only need that $f(x)$ is continuous at $x=0$.

Answer (score 2):

Good job. Your working seems fine.

It might be not clear to someone as pointed out in the comment about letting $t=1$. In that case, just state what  your $x$ is explicitly. Let $x=\frac{r}{e^{m}}, m \ge 0$ and hence we have $$f\left( \frac{r}{e^{m}}\right)=f\left(e\cdot \frac{r}{e^m} \right)$$ and $$f\left(e\cdot \frac{r}{e^m} \right)=f\left( \frac{r}{e^{m}}\right)$$

$$f\left(\frac{r}{e^{m-1}} \right)=f\left( \frac{r}{e^{m}}\right)$$

Remark:

Your working shows that the claim remains true for example if we restrict $t$ to be nonnegative integers.

Comment: Not sure why someone downvoted....

Answer (score 0):

Let me present alternative approach (assuming $f$ is not only *continuous*, but also *differentiable*).

Differentiate expression $f\left(x\right)=f\left(e^tx\right)$ with respect to $x$, get

$$
f\left(x\right)=f\left(e^tx\right) \implies 
f'\left(x\right)=f'\left(e^tx\right) e^t
$$

Differentiate the same expression $f\left(x\right)=f\left(e^tx\right)$ with respect to $t$ we get

$$
f\left(x\right)=f\left(e^tx\right) \implies 
f\left(x\right)=f'\left(e^tx\right) xe^t
$$

Then we conclude that ***either*** $f'\left(x\right) = 0\implies f\equiv \operatorname{const}$, ***or*** $xf'\left(x\right)=f\left(x\right)$.

Elaborating the latter case we get

$$
f'\left(x\right) = \frac{f\left(x\right)}{x} \implies
\frac{d f}{dx}=\frac{f}{x}\implies \frac{df}{f} = \frac{dx}{x}\implies f\left(x\right) = Cx
$$

where $C$ is a constant which we can compute by enforcing $f\left(x\right)=f\left(e^tx\right)$ which holds ***for any $x$***:

$$
Cx = Cxe^t, \quad t>0\;\implies \; C=0\;
\iff\; f\left(x\right)\equiv 0
$$

In either case, we get $ f\left(x\right)\equiv \operatorname{const}$.

Comment: You are not given that $f$ is differentiable.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my mistake

Comment: You can try and prove the same result but dropping even the continuity. Only using the equation given, you can prove that $f$ is constant for $x>0$, and constant (perhaps different) for $x<0$.

Comment: @elmer I would love to see the proof!

Answer (score 0):

Let $x$ be any real positive number. $f(x) = f(e^tx)$  $\forall t \ge 0$ can be rewritten as $f(x) = f(x_0)$, $ \forall x \ge x_0$, $ \forall x_0 \gt 0$. So $f(x)$ is constant over the positives.

Similarly, we have that for negative $x$, $f(x) = f(e^tx)$ for all $t \ge 0$ implies that $f(x) = f(x_0)$, $\forall x \le x_0$ $\forall x_0 \lt 0$. So $f(x)$ is constant over the negatives too.

So our function is constant over the positives and the negatives. Also, our function is continuous, so we can't have a discontinuity at $x = 0$. So f is continuous

Writing this because I didn't understand your method

Edit: maybe what I did isn't so trivial,but basically $e^t$ is a positive constant bigger than or equal to $ 1$. So any positive or negative real $x$ can be expressed as $e^tx_0$, for some non-negative $t$, for all $x_0$ such that $|x| \ge |x_0|$ and both have they same sign.

Another edit: Now I get your method. I was just seitching the variables around.

Answer (score 0):

Note that by simply setting $y=e^tx$ you get $f(y)=f(e^tx)=f(x)=f(e^{-t}y)$

So the restriction on $t\ge 0$ is just artificial and can be extended to negative $t$ as well.

Now just make $e^t\to 0$ and get the result by continuity as well.