# Showing $f(x)$ is constant

Tags: derivatives, solution-verification

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function such that for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and for all $t\geqslant 0$,$$f(x)=f(e^tx)$$Show that $f$ is a constant function.

---

We take $$\begin{aligned}
& \lim _{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} \\
= & \lim _{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f\left(e^t(x+h)\right)-f(x)}{h} \\
= & \lim _{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f\left(e^t x-e^t h\right)-f(x)}{h} \\
= & \frac{f\left(e^t x\right)-f(x)}{\lim _{h \rightarrow 0} h}=0 \Rightarrow f^{\prime}(x)=0
\end{aligned}$$ Hence, the function is differentiable and it's derivative is equal to $0$.
My concerns about this proof are:

1. Does the limit $\dfrac{f\left(e^t x\right)-f(x)}{\lim _{h \rightarrow 0} h}$ necessarily exist?
2. Seems like I didn't use the fact that $f(x)=f(e^tx)$ is true for all $t \geq 0$. In that case, is there any flaw in the solution.

Comment: The last two equalities before '$\Rightarrow f'(x)=0$' are both false.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2801327/624428

Comment: @geetha290krm i used continuity of $f$, so, $\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} f(e^t x+e^h)= f(\lim_{h \rightarrow 0}(e^t x+e^t h)= f(e^t x)$

Comment: You can't do this, because you have to consider that you're dividing by $h$ which is also going to 0. I.e., by your reasoning in the proof, let $g(x)$ be any continuous function, then $g'(x) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{g(x+h)-g(x)}{h} = \frac{g(x) - g(x)}{\lim_{h \to 0}h} = 0.$ This isn't true. Note that you can only split limits (i.e., $\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$ as $\lim_{h \to 0}(f(x+h)-f(x)/ \lim_{h \to 0}h$) if both limits exist, which they don't.

Comment: $f(1)=f(e^t)$ and $ f(-1)=f(-e^t)$ implies $f(x)=f(1)$ if $x>0$ and $f(x)=f(-1)$ if $x<0.$ Furthermore $f(1)=f(0)=f(-1)$ since  $f$ is continuous , in particular $f$ is continuous on zero. Do not try to use derivative since $f'(x)$ may not exist.

Answer (score 1):

> $$\begin{aligned}
> & \lim _{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f\left(e^t x-e^t h\right)-f(x)}{h} \\
> = & \frac{f\left(e^t x\right)-f(x)}{\lim _{h \rightarrow 0} h}
> \end{aligned}$$

This is not true! We are dividing by $h$ which approaches $0$, and we can't split the limits in this equation. The comments have already explained this, so I will not dwell further into this.

As for a correct solution, notice that we can repeatedly apply $f(x)=f(x/e^t)$ (the converse of the equation given). Hence, we get

$$
\forall x\in\mathbb{R}, f(x)=f(x/e^t)=f(x/e^{2t})=\dots \\
\implies\forall x\in\mathbb{R}, f(x)=\lim_{k\to+\infty}f(x/e^k)=\lim_{k\to+\infty}f(x/k)=f(0)
$$